# SQL Query -- Student Weighted Grade Calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I am having trouble calculating students grades together to get their final grade.

I have the following tables

```
Students
----------------
stu_id
stu_fname
stu_lname

Grades
----------------
grade_id
grade_name
grade_type
grade_possible

StudentGrades
-----------------
stu_grade_id
grade_id
stu_id
grade_earned

GradeTypes
----------------
grade_type
grade_type_name
grade_weight
```

This is the query that I have been able to come up with

```
Select S.stu_fname, S.stu_lname, GT.grade_type_name,         
(ROUND((SUM(SG.grade_earned)/SUM(G.grade_possible)), 2) * ROUND((GT.grade_weight/100.0)
, 2) ) as CalculatedGrade 
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN StudentGrade SG on SG.stu_id = S.stu_id
INNER JOIN Grade G on SG.grade_id = G.grade_id 
INNER JOIN GradeType GT WHERE G.grade_type = GT.grade_type
GROUP BY S.stu_fname, S.stu_lname, GT.grade_type_name;
```

I get the query report below

```
James | Fort | HW/QUIZ | 30.0 
James | Fort | LogBook | 60.0 
Robin | Hood | HW/QUIZ | 60.0 
Robin | Hood | Logbook | 25.0
```

I want to be able to add both of James Forts grades together to get his final grade and the same for Robin Hood.

Any help is appreciated, I am stuck at this point. I am almost done. I have researched sub queries and need more help to narrow my search to get the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry about that

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following ?

```
SELECT results.stu_fname, results.stu_lname, sum(results.CalculatedGrade)
FROM(  
     SELECT S.stu_fname, S.stu_lname, GT.grade_type_name,         
    (ROUND((SUM(SG.grade_earned)/SUM(G.grade_possible)), 2) * ROUND((GT.grade_weight/100.0)
    , 2) ) as CalculatedGrade 
    FROM Student S
    INNER JOIN StudentGrade SG on SG.stu_id = S.stu_id
    INNER JOIN Grade G on SG.grade_id = G.grade_id 
    INNER JOIN GradeType GT WHERE G.grade_type = GT.grade_type
    GROUP BY S.stu_fname, S.stu_lname, GT.grade_type_name
)results
GROUP BY results.stu_fname, results.stu_lname;
```

Edit: added aliases thanks to AshReva's remark.

Comment: This will fail. i think you should have alias on top select statements like results.stu_fname,results.stu_lname,sum(results.CalculatedGrade)

Comment: This query give me one grade for each student but it doesn't give the correct totals. I am not getting any grade over .2 For example the grades for one student is 8,21.25,24.75,18.40,5, and 10 but the query gives me the result of .1800

Comment: I have found the error. In your answer you didn't group by GT.grade_type_name along with the S.stu_fname and S.stu_lname. Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake while copy pasting your first query. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just remove `GT.grade_type_name` from the `select` and `group by`.  Does this do what you need?

```
Select S.stu_fname, S.stu_lname,     
       (ROUND((SUM(SG.grade_earned)/SUM(G.grade_possible)), 2) * ROUND((GT.grade_weight/100.0)
, 2) ) as CalculatedGrade 
FROM Student S INNER JOIN
     StudentGrade SG
     on SG.stu_id = S.stu_id INNER JOIN
     Grade G
     on SG.grade_id = G.grade_id INNER JOIN
     GradeType GT
     on G.grade_type = GT.grade_type
GROUP BY S.stu_fname, S.stu_lname;
```